# Set table values equal to value in other table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have one table which functions as a viewModel. From this, it is supposed to be the source of my binding in my view. My object is to update this table/viewModel based on two other tables. I have one property from each of the table checklistTable and AnswerTable that is to be set in my viewModel checkViewModel.

At the moment I am querying the current elements I need from each of the tables, and trying to update the viewModel.

CodeBehind:

```
//Curent descriptions to be set in the viewModel
var currentDescription = (_check.Where(s => currentElements.Contains(s.defineId)).Select(s=> s.Description).ToList());

//Current colors to be set in the viewModel
var currentColors = (from current in _answer
                    where current.questionId == currentCheckId && 
                    current.buildingId == currentBuildingId
                    orderby current.dateReported descending
                    select current.backgroundColor).ToList();
```

After retrieving theese values, i try to update my viewModel, and this is where things go wrong:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < currentDescription.Count() - 1; i++)
{
  currentViewTable.Description = currentDescription[i];
}
for (int i =0 ; i < currentColors.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    currentViewTable.backgroundColor.Insert(i,currentColors[i]);
}
```

I get the error: reference not set to an instance of an object. Are there better ways to update my viewModel, of or any tips on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate: "I have one table which funtctions as a viewModel"..
Show some xaml please.
What/Who is currentViewTable?

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend to use a foreach loop instead of a regular for loop. I find it much easier to use foreach when working with lists, this will eliminate any clear "off by one" errors usually.

```
foreach (var description in currentDescription)
{
    //do something given each element in the list
}
```

This seems to be a data integrity issue from what I can gather just looking at your code and given what the error is stating. I would recommend going into debug mode and looking in the Lists that you have generated to see if there are any indexes where the objects in your two lists are null, and handle these instances accordingly.